# JSF Passthrough element does not get it's value filed evaluated

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have an issue to fill property placeholder for JSF passthrough element:

**JSF:**

```html
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
<!-- ... -->
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{page.selectedCategoryDataKey}" id="mobileFilters" valueChangeListener="#{page.newCategorySelected}" layout="lineDirection" enhanced="true">
    <f:selectItem value="#{null}" itemLabel="#{messages.category_all}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{manager.dataEntryList}" var="categoryEntry" itemValue="#{categoryEntry.key}"
        itemLabel="#{categoryEntry.value.categoryName}"
        pt:data-track-name="See-#{categoryEntry.key}"/>
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form -list"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**HTML I get**

```html
<select id="mobileFilterSelectForm-mobileFilters" name="mobileFilterSelectForm-mobileFilters" size="1" onchange="m.ab(this,event,'valueChange','@this','@form list')"> <option value="" selected="selected">All</option>
 <option value="Some" data-track-name="See-">Some</option>
 <option value="Most Popular" data-track-name="See-">Most Popular</option>
 <option value="New" data-track-name="See-">New</option>
 <option value="Instant" data-track-name="See-">Instant</option>
</select>
```

As you can see *data-track-name* does not contain value concatenated to *See-* string, as it is evaluated to *itemValue* or *itemLabel*.

Can it be possible that passthrough does not evaluate placeholders as for regular JSF attributes? Any ideas how to get it evaluated?

Comment: Eventually I've ended up using c:forEach tag from xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core" instead of f:selectItems, that allowed to fill the data-track-name attribute value from a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `execute="@this"` then none of the input fields will be executed by the JSF framework. Set its value to `@parent` or `@form` or list the necessary input field IDs. Render just specify the components to be rendered. Execute specify what postback parameters to be converted, validated, event listeners called and copied to the model.

It should work:

```
<f:ajax execute="@parent".../>
```

Comment: I do not think that this is the issue with ajax part. I can remove the ajax tag at all, but the initial Select..Option block is still generated in a wrong way: attribute Value is correct, e.g. value="Some", but I expect that the same option tag will have data-track-name="See-Some" value. However, it does have only: data-track-name="See-" value.

Answer (score 0):

JSF will evaluate value expressions in the placeholder attributes. However as you've found it's not able to evaluate them when you're using the iteration var inside of selectItems; I tested both cases. It looks like a bug.